# JSON ( Windows 10 Universal C#)

Tags: c#, json, windows

```
[
    {
        "img":[
            "http://inventory.vibhavpatil.com/productimages/912b4loRgiL._UL1500_.jpg",
            "http://inventory.vibhavpatil.com/productimages/fdsfdsf.jpg"
        ],
        "Colour":[
            "Grey"
        ],
        "Size":[
            "Medium"
        ],
        "productcode":"0001",
        "productname":"Alan Jones Men\u0027s Cotton Printed T-Shirt",
        "productbrand":"sousamoda",
        "productcat":"clothing",
        "productsubcat":"t-shirt",
        "productmindec":"Look stylish and impressive",
        "actualprice":"899",
        "bestprice":"419",
        "quantity":"5",
        "designer":"Adidas"
    }
]
```

The above is my JSON output.

I could manage to get other single outputs such as product code etc.
But wanted help on how to get " img[0] " and "img[1]" image links. Below is my Code

```
class FullDetails
{
    public string productcode { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public string productbrand { get; set; }
    public string productcat { get; set; }
    public string productsubcat { get; set; }
    public string productmindec { get; set; }
    public string actualprice { get; set; }
    public string bestprice { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string designer { get; set; }      
    public List<string> img = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Colour = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Size = new List<string>();
}
```

My C# code

```
Array obj = JArray.Parse(urlContents);          

for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
{

    JObject row = JObject.Parse(obj[i].ToString());
    try
    {
        var item1 = new FullDetails();
        item1.productcode = row["productcode"].ToString();
        item1.productname = row["productname"].ToString();
        item1.productmindec = row["productmindec"].ToString();                   
        item1.actualprice = row["actualprice"].ToString();
        item1.bestprice = row["bestprice"].ToString();
        item1.productbrand = row["productbrand"].ToString();
        item1.productcat = row["productcat"].ToString();
        item1.productsubcat = row["productsubcat"].ToString();
        item1.quantity = row["quantity"].ToString();
        item1.designer = row["designer"].ToString();

        item1.img[0]= row["img"][0].ToString();                

        list1.Items.Add(item1);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: share Json code not share the image

Comment: @gencklavyeler    http://apisousa.vibhavpatil.com/justinproductsearch.aspx?p_code=0001 link will give the json output

Comment: @SirRufo well can i get code help?

Comment: I think he was very clear: **post the JSON as formatted plain text**, not as images, not as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the JSON, there's no need to get every item individually.

Just use some JSON tool, like [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and do this in one single line:

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FullDetails[]>(serialized);
```

I'm deserializing it to an array (`FullDetails[]`) because your URL returns an array (content is enclosed by `[` and `]`), even if the array has only one item.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to use Newtonsoft JSON attributes instead of manual parsing. Just to to "Nuget gallery" and type JSON, Newtonsoft package could be #1 in the search results.

Use it, hold it, love it. (c)